# Gradle build not adding all "private" libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies

I have a Java project that I am trying to build, I recently moved to gradle to be able to manage the dependencies faster and easier.

I am trying to use `gradle build`, with this result:

```
C:\whatever\>gradle build

:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:startScripts
:distTar
:distZip
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.75 secs
```

The library that is giving me problems is one that I have locally added like this:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libraries'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile name: 'jfxwrapper'
}
```

This is not the only library that I add to the project, but it's the only one that I built myself.

When I execute `gradle build` (or `gradlew build`, it seems to work exactly the same), it gives me a .jar in `build/libs/*.jar`, and then I try to execute this .jar it throws this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jfxwrapper.JFXWrapperScene

JFXWrapperScene is a class inside `jfxwrapper.jar`. I have used this library before adding it to the eclipse project path and it works just fine, but for some reason gradle doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Any explanation? Any idea of why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you for your patience.

**Update: I found out the problem was that I wasn't adding the libraries to the .jar, this piece of code adds all the referenced libraries to the .jar:**

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'MyTitle',
        'Implementation-Version': '1.1.1',
        'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

This adds all dependencies using `gradle fatJar`, but the project still doesn't work, it now says:

> Exception in Application start method

I know I have no exception in the start method, because I can run the same code if I export it using Eclipse.

Any suggestions? I am starting to believe switching to gradle was a big mistake, I might need to keep exporting with Eclipse, it's not so cool or fast, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution:

When compiling a JavaFX based program, you need to specify where the resources are (*.css, *.fxml, images....), in my case this piece of code worked:

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir 'pathToDirectory'
//For exmaple, in my case: 'src/main/java'
```

Comment: i got the same problem, even when i set sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir 'pathToDirectory'
//For exmaple, in my case: 'src/main/java'